# remove html template instance

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I have an app (a project for FreeCodeCamp) where a list of Twitch account are shown as either being online or offline.

The table I use is made from instances of a template of the form

```
 <template id="new-row">
   <td class="account-data logo"></td>
   <td class="account-data name"></td>
   <td class="account-data status></td>
    ...
  </template>
```

So each row is a unique instance of the template.

I need to be able to clear the table and reprint.

Any sort of .removeChild or .remove method either deletes the template itself and not the instances or does nothing.

Are there any alternatives here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to store the template inside a variable to make it safe from removal. Other ways include creating a  tag to contain the template content.

```
<script type="template/html" id='myTemplate'>
    <td class="account-data logo"></td>
    <td class="account-data name"></td>
    <td class="account-data status"></td>
</script>
```

Now you can use the following code to get the template

```
var template = $("#myTemplate").text();
```

Now to populate the table

```
function populateTableRows(rows) {
    var tbody = $("#myTable tbody");

    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = rows[i];
        var row = $("<tr>" + template + "</tr>");
        row.find("td:eq(0)").text(currentRow.logo);
        row.find("td:eq(1)").text(currentRow.name);
        row.find("td:eq(2)").text(currentRow.status);

        tbody.append(row);
    }
}
```

To clear the table

```
function clearTableRows() {
    var tbody = $("#myTable tbody");
    tbody.html("");
}
```

To make life easier you can use some templating library, some examples are

1. http://handlebarsjs.com/
2. https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a lot. I ended up having to repeat the append process with my column title, as they were getting removed with the table rows. I also had to use .html instead of .text since I had nested elements in the table that I didn't write out in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling the `.show()` or `.hide()` function would work? That or create a class that display's and hides what you want and use javascript to add the class or remove it.

Comment: I gave this a try, but no good. I think the issue is that I can't access the instance of template.